# How can Create Model class in swift and get values form model class in another class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

How can i create model class in Swift. I am getting errors wile accessing values form the model class. Thank you. [Here I am attaching my demo project, U can download it](https://www.facebook.com/download/100380210307053/ModelClasses.zip)

Comment: What error are you getting and on which line? provide some more detail about your problem.

Comment: var user : User = User() // here i am getting missing arguments
        print("\n First name :\( user.firstName) \t Last  name :\( user.lastName) Bio :\( user.bio)")

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/download/100380210307053/ModelClasses.zip this is demo project

Comment: add that into your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way you can add and get values from model class:

```
var user = User(firstName: "abcd", lastName: "efghi", bio: "biodata")
print("\n First name :\( user.firstName) \t Last  name :\( user.lastName) Bio :\( user.bio)")
```

OutPut will be:

```
 First name :abcd    Last  name :efghi Bio :biodata
```

**EDIT**

As per your requirement if you want to store object into your model class in AppDelegate then you have to create one global array of type User which will store your objects and when app loads you can append your object into that array with below code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

// Global array
var userData = [User]()

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let user = User(firstName: "Silviu", lastName: "Pop", bio: "I f**ing ♡ Swift!!!")
        //Add object into userData
        userData.append(user)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

}
```

Now you can access your save object this way In your `ViewController.swift` class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let user = userData
    println(user[0].firstName)
    println(user[0].lastName)
    println(user[0].bio)

}
```

And your OutPut will be:

```
Silviu
Pop
I f**ing ♡ Swift!!!
```

Comment: This is right but i want to access in another class

Comment: I am accessing it in `ViewController` class same way you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: see set in appdelegate like this in User(firstName: "abcd", lastName: "efghi", bio: "biodata")
 and get in viewcontroller  like this var objectType: User = User()
      print("\n First name :\( objectType.firstName) \t Last  name :\( objectType.lastName) Bio :\( objectType.bio)")

Comment: download demo project  https://www.facebook.com/download/100380210307053/ModelClasses.zip from this link and run you will get what is my requirement and error what i am getting

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Access-model-class-from-another-class

Comment: Got it Thanks, I am searching from long back about this, But i haven't find any solution.. You Done it :)   : Dharmesh Kheni its working

Comment: i have made simple demo app please check it once https://github.com/pprravinn/Model