# Create Model With Server Reponse with Swift Json

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

Hi all  how do i create a model class with this kind of response in swift using SiwftJson am not sure how to include this

"total_songs": 12,
  "title": "Arun Thapa",
  "result": "success",
  "favorite": "false",
  "cover": "artists/4096759431451532756hqdefault.jpg"  in model using below response

```
{
  "total_favorite": 0,
  "Data": [
    [
      {
        "album_song_id": "120",
        "artist_name": "Arun Thapa",
        "status": "1",
        "song_duration": "245213",
        "song_favorite": "false",
        "albumb_name": "Arun Thapa",
        "created_by": "1",
        "created_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "albumb_id": "42",
        "chart_name": "Evergreen Songs",
        "song_lyrics": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n\t<title></title>\r\n</head>\r\n<body></body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
      }
    ]
  "total_songs": 12,
  "title": "Arun Thapa",
  "result": "success",
  "favorite": "false",
  "cover": "artists/4096759431451532756hqdefault.jpg"
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914758/how-can-create-model-class-in-swift-and-get-values-form-model-class-in-another-c and better is follow tutorial like https://makeapppie.com/2014/06/20/swift-swift-adding-an-mvc-model-class-in-swift/

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how to map JSON to a struct. I hope you can start with this piece of code.

Pay attention to optional and not-optional values.

```
struct SomeDataModel {
    let totalFavorites: Int
    let totalSongs: Int
    // other properties go here

    init(withJson json: JSON) {
        self.totalFavorites = json["total_favorites"].intValue
        self.totalSongs = json["total_songs"].intValue
        // initialization of other properties go here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your JSON data missing "]," in end of "Data".
So correct JSON according me :

```
{
  "total_favorite": 0,
  "Data": [
           [
             {
               "album_song_id": "120",
                "artist_name": "Arun Thapa",
                "status": "1",
                "song_duration": "245213",
                "song_favorite": "false",
                "albumb_name": "Arun Thapa",
                "created_by": "1",
                "created_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "albumb_id": "42",
                "chart_name": "Evergreen Songs",
                "song_lyrics": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n\t<title></title>\r\n</head>\r\n<body></body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
              }
           ]
         ],
  "total_songs": 12,
  "title": "Arun Thapa",
  "result": "success",
  "favorite": "false",
  "cover": "artists/4096759431451532756hqdefault.jpg"
}
```

And i suggest one json To Swift model converter, you need to just simple put JSON and you get swift model file. 
    If you don't need extra code you can remove it from swift model file.

Link of JSON to SWIFT MODEL CONVERTER - http://www.json4swift.com

Comment: @dirtydanee - check now

Comment: The suggested generator produces quite bad quality code... If someone just starts learning it is always better do not use existing solutions and tools.

Comment: @Meet yes it generated two files with response and how to call and show in tableview to show data

Comment: @AndreyGershengoren yes  and can u show me model class using swiftyjson for above response

Comment: @IOS_PROGRAMMER I'm wondering if you even took a look at SwiftyJson documentation? Just create a struct that describes your json model, pass JSON in init function as parameter and then populate sctruct's properties

Comment: @AndreyGershengoren i created model properly and initialised properly but "total_songs": 12,
  "title": "Arun Thapa",
  "result": "success",
  "favorite": "false",
  "cover": "artists/4096759431451532756hqdefault.jpg"  not sure how to initialise along with these variables in model so i want to see it  like the variables out of dictionary how to do it with  and am new to swifty josn just started using it

Comment: Hi @AndreyGershengoren I'd like to learn what's bad in the quality of code from the generator and how would a good quality code for such functionality look like?